# Zend router config xml, shortcut?

Tags: xml, config, router, zend-route

I have an xml like this

```
<configdata>
    <routes>
        <home type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
            <route>home</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </defaults>
        </home>
    </routes>
</configdata>
```

Now this works but I'd like to give each rout a shortcut like you would add in bootstrap like this..

```
$router->addRoute('shortcut_key',$route);
```

How can I do this in the config xml?

Answer (score 0):

On your bootsrap.php...

```
protected function _initRoutes()
 {
  $routefile = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/routes.xml');
  $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
  $router->addConfig($routefile);
  return $router;
 }
```

where routes.xml file is the xml file containing all routes and it must be inside your application folder